# Updating closed issues on Github

Tags: github

I have forked a Github repo to update. There is a single master branch. The author had created Github issues and has closed them. Now I need to update them.

Is there any way?

Comment: You can still write comments on closed issues. Or what else do you mean by "updating" them?

Comment: Update means updating the code base. Ex, I need to upgrade Java 11 to Java 17 in the pom.xml of the project.

Comment: Then you mean pull requests. They are not usually called "issues" even though they look somewhat the same in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues and pull requests can still be edited when they are closed/merged. Attention though, the issues and pull requests are only present on the original repository. They don't get transferred when forking.